Why does simulation differ each other in ngspice and LTspice?
I am a novice to ngspice when it comes to NMOS parameter.
This is the schematics in LTspice.

And this is netlist generated by LTspice.
M1 Vo VG2 VX 0 NMOS-SH l=1u w=20u
Vicm1 Vicm 0 0.655
Vid1 Vid 0 0.5 AC 1
VB1 VB 0 1.3
VDD1 VDD 0 1.8
B2 VG2 0 V=V(Vicm)
R1 VX 0 1k
R2 N001 VX 2k
B1 N001 0 V=V(Vid)
I1 VDD Vo 2.90978e-006
.model NMOS NMOS
.model PMOS PMOS
.lib C:\Users\kile\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.mos
.MODEL NMOS-SH nmos(kp=180u,vto=0.4, lambda = {0.1/1}, gamma = 0.5, phi = 0.7)
.MODEL PMOS-SH pmos(kp=45u,vto=-0.42, lambda = {0.14/1}, gamma = 0.5, phi = 0.7)
;dc Vicm1 0 1.8 0.01
;dc VB1 0 1.8 0.01
;tf V(Vo) Vid1
.op
.backanno
.end

Then I use this netlist directly in ngspice.
I got different V(Vo) in .op (dc analysis). In ngspice, it's 2.909780e-06 volts. In LTpice,  it's  0.946482 volts.
Which one should I trust.

Confidence comes after learning the tool you understand best how to use and the differences in models or run parameters. But I would not be confident of too many sigfigs considering Vt tolerances.

read /  Compare log for errors.

kile, Did you notice the the ngspice number you report is exactly the same as the current source magnitude? Separately, what do you work out by hand as the correct answer?

@periblepsis My hand calculation suggest that Ltspice is correct. But I don't know how to correct it in ngspice and what's wrong in ngspice.

@D.A.S. I know there is log in Ltspice. But I couldn't find log in ngspice. Can you give me more details?

@kile So this is really an ngspice question, not an LTspice one. I don't use ngspice, don't have it installed, and can't help test it for you. But since QSPICE is completely free and written by the same author as LTspice but much newer, you might also try the netlist on it, as well. Just as a check. I'm pretty sure that Mike wrote far better code this time around. So it might be worth a shot.

I dont use ngspice or qspice but I tried the latter, changed your path and tried it.  It gave 2 error messages (could not create file...) with no useful help.  Where did you find this .asc file? Why not  zip it here for others to help you.
